# Protocol Buffer Specificity

Tags: python, c++, serialization, protocol-buffers, messaging

I recently started integrating Google's Protocol Buffer for the communication of more complex data structures in a robotic network (e.g. matrices, internal state arrays, device info).

While I'm still at the prototyping phase, I've begun wondering how specific I should make the proto messages for long-term support. I see three possible approaches (very simple examples):

1) Medium specificity: Make the messages specific to each type of robot. Ex:

```
// RobotA.proto
optional int32 commandID
repeated double positionData //ex: this robot has many joints

// RobotB.proto
optional int32 commandID
optional int32 subCommandID //ex: this robot has subcommands
optional double positionData //ex: this robot has only one joint
```

2) Low specificity: Make the messages very general. Ex:

```
// GeneralRobotMessage.proto
optional int32 commandID //switch-case which other potential data is needed
optional int32 potentialIntData 
repeated double potentialDoubleArray
optional string potentialStringData
optional bool potentialBoolData
```

3) High specificity: Each type of message has a protobuf. Ex:

```
// NAKMessage.proto
// ACKMessage.proto
// RobotAGetPosition.proto
```

From past experience, I usually employ a low specificity approach and use command IDs (aka a packet header) to designate the approach to parsing the message. But with protobufs, the whole concept of a predesignated .proto seems to act as a header concept.

Is there a recommended approach to message specificity? Coding standards? Rule of thumb?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's mostly a matter of taste (makes this Q borderline off-topic.)

I would read, and follow, the [proto3 guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3) and [style guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/style).

As a tip I would recommend specifying fields and messages that you use to distinguish the messages on a specific recipient specifically so that parsing gets easier.

Also keep all entities [optional](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#optional) if possible, then you can change the format later and it will still be backwards compatible.

[Nested](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#nested) messages might also be an alternative, you can make a hierarchy like:

```
message Robot{
    optional uint32 id = 1;
    optional RobotTypeA robo_type_a = 2;
    optional RobotTypeB robo_type_b = 3;

    message RobotTypeA {
     optional uint32 a = 1;
     optional uint32 b = 2;
     optional uint32 c = 3;
     optional uint64 d = 4;
     optional int32 command_id = 5;
     optional string ip_address = 6 [default = "10.10.10.10"];
    }

    message RobotTypeB {
     optional uint32 a = 1;
     optional uint32 b = 2;
     optional uint32 c = 3;
     optional uint64 d = 4;
     optional int32 command_id = 5;
     optional string ip_address = 6 [default = "10.10.10.10"];
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually quite like the concept of the nested messages, it allows for a nice mix of specificity. Yes, optional is the way to go (I assume you also endorse repeated fields as they're optional as well).

Comment: Sure `repeated` fields are very useful, just remember to specify `[packed=true]` to [optimize encoding](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#specifying-field-rules).